# object does not live long enough when implementing the `From` trait

Tags: rust

My code has a '... does not live long enough error' error when I implement the `From<T>` trait for `FileSlice`, because the `FlieSlice` reference to the argument of the `from` method, and the argument dropped when the method returned.

Is there some way the solve this problem? Thank you.

```rust
struct FileSlice {
    data: Box<dyn FileHandle>,
}

trait FileHandle {
    fn read(&self, range: Range<usize>);
}

impl FileHandle for &'static [u8] {
    fn read(&self, range: Range<usize>) {
        let a = &self[range];
        println!("{:?}", a);
    }
}

impl<T> From<T> for FileSlice
where
    T: Deref<Target = [u8]> + 'static,
{
    fn from(a: T) -> Self {
        let b: &'static [u8] = a.deref(); //error: 'a' does not live long enough.
        FileSlice { data: Box::new(b) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Deref::deref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#tymethod.deref) has the signature:

```rust
fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target
```

Or, desugared:

```rust
fn deref<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a Self::Target
```

It *borrows* `self`, and returns a reference with the same lifetime. Because of that, if you want the resulting reference to be `'static`, you need `&self` to be `&'static self`. `T: 'static` is not related: it means `self` is static, but `&self` is the address of the parameter `a`, which is obviously not `'static`. What you need is:

```rust
impl<T> From<&'static T> for FileSlice
where
    T: Deref<Target = [u8]>,
{
    fn from(a: &'static T) -> Self {
        let b: &'static [u8] = a.deref();
        FileSlice { data: Box::new(b) }
    }
}
```